# Git Log in Powershell

Tags: powershell

My command is to pull log from repository based on a previous tag till the latest HEAD. Below is the command i run in powershell

```
git log 10.01.39.000..head --oneline --name-only --pretty=format:
```

The same when i try to do it by substituting a variable in place of the tag name does not give me the output. Should the .. be escaped in powershell? Powershell is considering the ..Head as a method for the variable.

```
git log $tag..head --oneline --name-only --pretty=format:
```

Comment: You should try either `"$tag..HEAD"` or `"$($tag)..HEAD"`, one of those should work, but you should include the double quotes, otherwise Powershell might separate on .. and add some spaces (has been my experience)

Comment: "$tag..HEAD" worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Also, you should in general get in the habit of typing `HEAD` in all caps, or use its one-character synonym `@`. Lowercase `head` sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, and when it doesn't, the result can be pretty bad sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you want to:

- Force expansion of `$tag` before passing the argument to `git`
- Prevent evaluation of the `..` operator

The easiest way to do this is to construct an expandable string literal using `"`:

```
git log "$tag..head" --oneline --name-only --pretty=format:...
```

Comment: This saved me further days in debugging azure pipeline scripts!